# Can Flink handle ~50 GB of state for a single table/window?

Tags: scala, hashmap, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am building a streaming analytic that requires ~50 GB of initial state in-memory for a single table. ~50 GB is the amount of RAM used when I load the state into a Scala HashMap[String,String].

Can Flink handle having ~50 GB of state for a single table that grows over time?

Will I be able to perform lookups and updates to this table in a streaming fashion?

Notes:

- I cannot change the types to anything smaller.
- The state is used as a lookup for mapping one String to another String.
- It would take like three years for the state to double to 100 GB (aggressive estimate as the current state required ten years to produce).
- This Flink blog claims that the state size should not be a problem but I thought I would double check before spinning it up. Terabytes of state are mentioned.

  - https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/01/30/incremental-checkpointing.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

50-100 GB for a single table in Flink state is not a problem.

But to be clear, when we talk about having huge amounts of state in Flink (e.g., terabytes) we are talking about keyed state that is sharded across many parallel tasks. Yes, you can have a single table that is very large, but any given instance will only have a subset of the rows of that table.

Note that you will need to choose a state backend -- either a heap-based state backend that will keep the state in memory, as objects on the JVM heap, or the RocksDB state backend, that will keep the state as serialized bytes on disk with an in-memory cache.

Comment: The blog that I referenced indicates that RocksDB should  be used. I’ll give that a shot. Thanks.

Comment: @AetherMass curious how that's going for you so far. my team has run into a plethora of flink issues and are actually considering replacing flink with our own code. I think the RocksDB was the last straw for us because it actually ran into performance issues with handling the amount of state (terabytes) we needed

Comment: @dtc It would be valuable to understand the issues you've run into with RocksDB. Also, you may want to investigate the new state backend that is being developed. See https://flink-packages.org/packages/spillable-state-backend-for-flink, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-50%3A+Spill-able+Heap+Keyed+State+Backend,  and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12692.

Comment: @dtc I left that position a few months ago (startup issues) but we were humming along with Flink. RocksDB helped with most state that we had; it ended up in the range of 5-10 GB. I had transactional end-to-end messaging working and tests to verify. For that use case, Flink worked great. More state would have been needed as we added capabilities. I do not know where the ceiling was. At one point, I had custom functions that just stored data in memory (not my code). On start, we suppressed output and loaded state to populate those tables. I was migrating that code to use Flink's state services.